# How to mask field values to some specific users?

Tags: sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014, we always run our queries from our server side code as a specific SQL **"system"** user. However, there is an **"app user"** in any given query context.

So, when a query like this is run:

**select field1 from table1;**

Our business wants field1 value to be masked based on the "app user". Info on which field should be masked for which app user is/can be setup in the database.

What is the best way to support this in SQL 2014? Seems like I might have to start by building a view, even so, how do I go about masking some column values there based on the current app user?

Comment: "The best way" would be to upgrade to a more recent version of SQL Server and use [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2016).

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately, can't upgrade now.